# tt_address: extended fields not shown in backend after update to Typo3 6.2

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, kickstarter

I have a backend-problem with Typo3 6.2 and my tt_address extended fields:
In Typo3 4.5 I extended the tt_address database-fields with a little extension built with kickstarter. After the update to Typo3 6.2 these fields disappeared in the backend so I can't edit them anymore.
In the Frontend everything is fine, all fields are there.
Any idea, how I can access these fields again in the backend?
Here's the content of my ext_tables.php:

```
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) { die ('Access denied.'); }

$tempColumns = array (
    'tx_ttaddressextended_kuerzel' => array (       
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_kuerzel',      
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',  
            'size' => '30', 
            'max' => '2',
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_kurzwahl' => array (      
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_kurzwahl',     
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',  
            'size' => '30',
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_by_tema' => array (       
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_by_tema',      
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',  
            'size' => '30',
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_ausbildung' => array (        
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_ausbildung',       
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_abschluss' => array (     
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_abschluss',        
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',  
            'size' => '30',
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_sprachen' => array (      
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_sprachen',     
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',  
            'size' => '30',
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_laufbahn' => array (      
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_laufbahn',     
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_auszeichnungen' => array (        
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_auszeichnungen',       
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_besondere_projekte' => array (        
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_besondere_projekte',       
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_aktiv' => array (     
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_aktiv',        
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_ttaddressextended_interessen' => array (        
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tt_address_extended/locallang_db.xml:tt_address.tx_ttaddressextended_interessen',       
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => '30',
            'rows' => '5',
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 2,
                'RTE' => array(
                    'notNewRecords' => 1,
                    'RTEonly'       => 1,
                    'type'          => 'script',
                    'title'         => 'Full screen Rich Text Editing|Formatteret redigering i hele vinduet',
                    'icon'          => 'wizard_rte2.gif',
                    'script'        => 'wizard_rte.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
);

//t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_address');
if (version_compare(TYPO3_branch, '6.1', '<')) {
    t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_content');
}
t3lib_extMgm::addTCAcolumns('tt_address',$tempColumns,1);
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_address',
  'tx_ttaddressextended_kuerzel;;;;1-1-1, 
   tx_ttaddressextended_kurzwahl, 
   tx_ttaddressextended_by_tema, 
   tx_ttaddressextended_ausbildung;;;richtext[]:rte_transform[mode=ts], 
   tx_ttaddressextended_abschluss, 
   tx_ttaddressextended_sprachen, 
   tx_ttaddressextended_laufbahn;;;richtext[]:rte_transform[mode=ts], 
   tx_ttaddressextended_auszeichnungen;;;richtext[]:rte_transform[mode=ts], 
   tx_ttaddressextended_besondere_projekte;;;richtext[]:rte_transform[mode=ts], 
   tx_ttaddressextended_aktiv;;;richtext[]:rte_transform[mode=ts], 
   tx_ttaddressextended_interessen;;;richtext[]:rte_transform[mode=ts]'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead class t3lib_extMgm try use ExtensionManagementUtility:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_address', $tempColumns, 1);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_address', '...');
```

[ExtensionManagementUtility Class Reference >>](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html)

Comment: Hi Robert, I changed it, but the result is the same: the additional fields aren't shown in the Backend :(

Comment: I also tried just `ExtensionManagementUtility::add...` but than I receive an error (in one point a good thing because so I know the extension is loaded).

Comment: Hello, please try reinstall your extension (which extends tt_address) and clean system and general cache in Typo3 backend.

Comment: If that fails, you can send me your extension (zip)?

Comment: Still not working. How can i send you the extension?

Comment: Upload ZIP to any public URL and paste link to comment, if You can.

Comment: No problem: [downloads.tietz-munoz.de/tt_address_extended.zip](http://downloads.tietz-munoz.de/tt_address_extended.zip)

Comment: I installed EXT tt_address 3.0.0 and EXT tt_address_extended on Typo3 6.2.4. All works fine! Try reinstall both extensions and clean cache. Your code looks OK. [Screenshot form BE](http://eraled.sk/typo3temp/backed-screenshot.png)

Comment: Hi Robert, thanx for your effort. I updated tt_address to 3.0 and now I can see all fields. :-) 
But now I have problems with the wt_directory extension (which I use for the output and don't work propper with 6.2)

Comment: Last version of wt_directory is not compatible with Typo3 6.x - https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/wt_directory - Compatibility 4.0.0 - 4.7.99. I can not help You. You must check PHP errors/warnigns and manually update wrong code. It is only way.